# How to insert all records of a table in another table using a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I got a table with approx 13066 records in which I want to add all other records from another table (having approx. 1346 records).  There is a stored procedure which does the insert and I want to use it for all records to be inserted.  Can anyone please help?

Comment: What is the structure for both tables?

Comment: both tables have same structure, basically they are identical.  I need to run the stored procedure because it caters for some cells which are filled through it by checking with existing data in table with 13066 records.

Comment: What are the parameters to your existing stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have misinterpreted your question but it seems like that you want to execute a stored procedure and insert the results of the stored procedure in to your main table.

To do this you can do:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourMainTable
EXEC dbo.YourStoredProcedureName
```

**EDIT:**

The only way I can think of doing this would be to use a cursor.

```
DECLARE @PrimaryKeyFieldInTable2 int

DECLARE spCur CURSOR LOCAL FOR

   SELECT PrimaryKetCol From Table2

OPEN spCur

FETCH NEXT FROM spCur INTO @PrimaryKeyFieldInTable2


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.Table1
    EXEC dbo.YourStoredProceudre @PrimaryKeyFieldInTable2

    FETCH NEXT FROM spCur INTO @PrimaryKeyFieldInTable2 

END

CLOSE spCur
DEALLOCATE spCur
```

This assumes that your Stored Procedure accepts one parameter to select each row from Table2.

This isn't the best use of SQL Server but if you really must do it this way then I can't think of any other way.

Comment: Let me try to explain myself better.  I have a table1 which I want all the data of table 2 in it.  Now there is a stored procedure that already does this but only for one record.  I want to use this stored procedure to input all records of table 2 in table 1

Comment: @IanCian: That is silly. You'd loop through every row in table2 rather than doing a straight insert like I did. The condition in your stored proc can be put into the INSERT..SELECT. I'm going to downvote your question for asking for a loop. @Barry: +1 for your interpretation

Comment: @IanCian: you can do this but depending on the performance of your stored procedure, it can be sloooooooow for thousands calls in a row.

Comment: I have updated my answer. If you really MUST do it this way then a cursor is probably the only way.  It's not something I'd recommend doing very often though.

Comment: @gbn: please don't down vote. Not every one on stack overflow is obliged to know, that loops in database is a terrible choice most of the time. We as community might try and explain this. Also, in *his* case having a loop could be acceptable. He just wants to reuse any business logic that is already coded into the stored procedure, it's a very natural desire. If, for example the amount of data he is going to insert is small and the stored procedure is relatively (to his constraints) quick, there is nothing wrong with quick and dirty coding of a loop. Ever heard about "throw-away" code? =)

Comment: @zespri: isn't just for the loops. The true question emerged over several comments rather than in the question. I have allowed for the fact that OP may not be native English speaking: even so, the questions is misleading and wasted time.

Comment: sorry if i was not so clear in my question, I admit I could have put the question in a more understandable way.  10x for this answer (cursor) it was I was looking for.  I did not want to use loops because the script I am generating must be reusable and most of the time there are alot more of records to be processed.

Comment: @IanCian - To be honest, this solution isn't much better than using a while loop.  Performance for cursors are generally poor. You should look in to refactoring your existing stored procedure to handle multiple rows as @gbn has already stated. I appreciate that this solution may answer your question but you should look in to refactoring as it may well save you a lot of time in the long term.

Answer (score 6):

It is this simple unless you haven't given all information, such as "there are duplicates" or "only if not already there"

```
CREATE PROC DoSomething
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT table1 (col1, col2, etc)
SELECT col1, col2, etc FROM table2
GO
```

Edit:

There is something missing.

OP wants a loop through table2 to be able to call an existing stored procedure

To do it properly you'd use

```
INSERT table1 (col1, col2, etc)
SELECT col1, col2, etc FROM table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 t1
                    WHERE t1.key = t2.key and <some conditions>)
```

Comment: I have already a stored procedure called stp_dosomethingInsert which must be used because it caters for some cells which are filled through it by checking with existing data in table with 13066 records

Comment: I need a way to loop through table 2 (one being inserted) and add records one by one using this stored procedure. any suggestions pls

Comment: @IanCian: so your stored procedure returns one row at a time? What have the 2nd table got to do with the stored procedure

Comment: my stored procedure makes an INSERT of one row at a time.  I need to use it to insert all data from table 2 to table 1 at one go.

Comment: @IanCian: that would be a loop through table2. Which is silly